# Export to excel button not working in Edge browser

Tags: kendo-grid, microsoft-edge, export-to-excel

Export excel button of kendo grid is not working in MS Edge browser.
The same thing is working in IE11 and Chrome browsers.

No error messages are shown.

Edge is of version 42.17134.1.0.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with the kendo grid example from this link.

[Grid / Export to Excel](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export)

I tested with **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0** and find that Export to Excel button is working fine.

This is the testing result.

[image]

So there is no issue with Edge browser on my side.

It can be possible that some other thing caused this issue on your side. You can try to visit the above link and try to run that demo on your side to check whether it is working or not.

If issue persist than try to provide detailed information about your issue. We will again try to check the issue and try to provide suggestions for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old App, then it may still be using the Kendo scripts from **2015**.
This issue was fixed in **Q1 2016**:
    https://www.telerik.com/forums/excel-export-not-working-in-edge

It may be time for an upgrade.
Better yet, replace Kendo by rolling your own Grid
You could replace other Kendo UI features by using opensource alternatives like jQuery UI.
It is easier to create your own now, using the modern web building frameworks of today.

However, if you're stuck with millions of lines of Legacy Code and an outdated framework (like Web Forms), then I understand not wanting to change anything, other than updating the Kendo Scripts.